# How to use Jest to mock onTouchStart for touchscreen usecase in unit test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

Hi I have a simple state that checking is the device touchable by using 'ontouchstart' in window here. And will add div class base on the conditioning below. And need to write a unit test for this scenario. I want to ask what the proper way to mock the touch case scenario in jest. Any one can help?

```
this.state = {
            touchable: true
        };

this.state.touchable = 'ontouchstart' in window;

<div class=`${state.touchable ? touchable : ''}`>
</div>
```

Unit Test file here
I trying to test if the device is touchable, then the div should have class "touchable"

```
describe('Given touch device', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    window.ontouchstart = jest.fn()
  })

  it('should have class touchable', async () => {
    const { container } = await render(template, mockData)
    const container = container.querySelector('div')
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(container).toHaveClass('touchable')
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: You're missing quotes in your template - `${state.touchable ? 'touchable' : ''}`